# Counting total number of Functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Suppose F be the set of one-to-one functions from the set $1,2,..,n$ to the set $1,2,...,m$ where $m \geq n \geq 1$. Then how many functions f in F satisfy the property $f(i)<f(j)$ for some $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$.

How to count total no. of functions, What will be the approach.

Comment: If a function does not satisfy that property, it is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Arthur: You must mean weakly decreasing.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen No, all functions are specified to be injective, so decreasing means strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Arthur: Right. I never understand why people who mean "injective" say something else (same for "surjective"), and in the end, I often overlook when they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Arthur points out, $f$ fails to satisfy that property iff $f$ is decreasing (strictly, since $f$ is $1$-to-$1$).  A strictly decreasing function is uniquely determined by its range, which is an $n$-subset of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$.  So there are $m\choose n$ strictly decreasing functions.  All other functions in $F$ satisfy the given property; as $|F|=m(m-1)\cdots (m-n+1)$, the count is $m(m-1)\cdots (m-n+1)-{m\choose n}$.

Comment: $m^n$ is wrong, you're forgetting the one-to-one condition.

Comment: @Arthur -- right, thanks!